# Queue<T> thread-safety: one writer, one reader

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, queue

I've got a `Queue<T> _q = new Queue<T>();`

There's always only one thread populating it: `_q.Enqueue(msg);`

There's always only one thread consuming it: `_q.Dequeue();`

I want to be lock-free in both threads. Performance is important but safety is on the first place.

Do I need making `_q` a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`?

**UPD**
That can be important:
I do not need to be sure that reading thread will successfully dequeue item immediatly after writing thread enqueues it. If a few `false` dequeues will be taken - that's ok.

Comment: Why does it need to be lock-free?  The `ConcurrentQueue` uses locks (ones that you don't have to handle yourself) and uses spinning (I think) to then try access the queue.

Comment: You right about `ConcurrentQueue`. It uses spinning which is a kind of lock. But I think it still better than `lock(_q) { ... }`. The main reason not to use locks is performance. Writing thread must not meet someone's lock on the way. It's a server

Comment: You can surely make a queue that has this performance.  As long as the item is inserted into the queue storage ny a single producer before the 'front' index is updated, the single consumer cannot take a false entry.  Whether 'Queue' has such a guarantee is another matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need making _q a ConcurrentQueue

Yes. A Queue is not thread safe.

Comment: Does that matter it my particular case of reading it? What can happen?

Comment: @astef Enqueue and TryDequeue would both be changing the queue, so the usual culprit race conditions - which is random bad stuff happening.

Comment: what's the worst thing can happen? Exception somewhere? Wrong order of items?

Comment: @astef: That, and missing/duplicate items eventually.

Comment: ...And then the Control Rods fail to drop during a power outage. ;)

Comment: Found a mistake. `Queue` does not have `TryDequeue` method, only `Dequeue`. And now it really looks like not safe

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find a lock free queue: [Lockfreie threadsichere Queue](http://www.mycsharp.de/wbb2/thread.php?threadid=69007) - don't be afraid of the site being in german - the code should speak for itself. Furthermore, there's another, little more in-depth article at [Writing Lock-Free Code: A Corrected Queue](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/writing-lock-free-code-a-corrected-queue/210604448)

Comment: Are you sure that is better choice than `ConcurrentQueue<T>`?

Comment: Well, I wasn't aware of ConcurrentQueue being lock-free. In this case I would prefer the framework class over adding another one.

Comment: Yes, `ConcurrentQueue` isn't lock free. It uses spin locks.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `syncQueue = Queue.Synchronized(_q);`, though that uses locks internally.